# How to redirect all pages of site A, including those with query strings, to homepage of site B

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

I want to redirect all pages of `SiteA` to homepage of `SiteB`.
I used this code in SiteA's `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://SiteB.tld/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The code works perfectly, but not for URLs with `Question Mark`, such as

```
https://SiteA.tld/?action=dayview&calendar=1&year=2000&month=01&day=01
```

This pages will get `404 Not Found` and wouldn't redirect to SiteB's hompage.
What changes should I make in the Redirection code?

Comment: Redirecting everything to a home page is not usually good for either users or for SEO.   It is almost always better to redirect users to the same page on another site if it exists or to give them an error message explaining why it is gone.

Comment: "This pages will get 404 Not Found and wouldn't redirect to SiteB's hompage." - Are you saying that SiteA triggers the 404 and the user is not redirected to SiteB at all? What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: SiteA and its directories removed totally. SiteA's directories does not exist in SiteB. So, to use its DA and PA we decided to redirect its pages to an homepage of SiteB with related data. @stephen-ostermiller

Comment: For pages with Question Mark, SiteA redirected to SiteB, but this pages get 404 Not Found in SiteB and wouldn't redirect to SiteB's homepage. The `QSD` flag has made everything OK. @DocRoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the "query string discard" or `QSD` flag to your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://SiteB.tld/ [R=301,QSD,L]
```

From the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd):

> When the requested URI contains a query string, and the target URI does not, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to copy that query string to the target URI. Using the `[QSD]` flag causes the query string to be discarded.
>
> This flag is available in version 2.4.0 and later.
>
> Using `[QSD]` and `[QSA]` together will result in `[QSD]` taking precedence.
>
> If the target URI has a query string, the default behavior will be observed - that is, the original query string will be discarded and replaced with the query string in the `RewriteRule` target URI.